# Specific redirection in .htaccess does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a specific problem with my mod_rewrite configuration that I cannot resolve. I am no admin, therefore I'm kindly asking for a collective advice :) Please note - it's not a general question about redirection, but very specific one.

### Story

I have a shared hosting with access to FTP and ability to create my own `.htaccess` files. This shared hosting had plenty of files and directories before I created the website, so logical step for me was to place everything inside `new-site` folder.

Then I had to create custom rewrite rules so that everything under `example.com` points to `new-site`.

### CONFIG

So I came up with the following config.

```
# (...) other rules

# 1. Make sure that /new-site/ is not a duplicated content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new-site/
RewriteRule ^/new-site/(.*)$ /$1  [R=301,L]

# 2. Make sure that example.com is internally handled by files in '/new-site'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new-site/$1
```

### RESULTS

Rule marked with `2.` works fine, my site is accessible as I want. However I didn't want `https://example.com/new-site/` to be found on the server by bots and treated by a duplicated content, so I added rule `1.`.

**This rule, however, doesn't seem to have any effect!** I looked it up with CURL and request is handled immediately with a `200` status. I'm banging my head against the wall and experimenting with other variants of it, but everything fails.

What I'm after is pretty darn simple:

1. Make every request to the root domain be handled by website which is stored in `/new-site/`
2. Make sure that direct call to `https://example.com/new-site/(.*)` is redirected with `301` status back to the domain root.

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

I've noticed that my setup seems to be doing far better if I remove a child `.htaccess` file under `/new-site/` subfolder. I didn't mention it in my original question because there is nothing special about it (just some SEO rewrites).

```
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^products$ products.php
# (...) similar rewrites
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your first rule **never matches** because it **must not begin** with a *leading slash*.

   With `RewriteRule`, you only need a leading slash if you're directly in `httpd.conf` or before Apache v2.4 i think.
2. While you have a good idea, your first rule will cause an infinite redirection loop if it's working. You have to use `THE_REQUEST` to match direct user request only.

You can put this code in `/.htaccess`

```
# 1. Make sure that /new-site/ is not a duplicated content
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/new-site/([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# 2. Make sure that example.com is internally handled by files in '/new-site'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!new-site/).*)$ /new-site/$1 [L]
```

Also, you'll have to add this line in `/new-site/.htaccess` (to avoid automatic override)

`RewriteOptions InheritBefore`

Comment: we are close but not there yet :) Your rules work fine, but only if I don't have any `.htaccess` in my `new-site` folder. I didn't mention it before because I didn't know it was significant. But your rules work if I remove it and do not work if I keep it. I added my 2nd `.htaccess` to the question, mind having a look?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed significant. That's the default behaviour of htaccess files (subfolder htaccess overrides parent htaccess). To avoid it, you can add this line in your subfolder htaccess: `RewriteOptions InheritBefore`

Comment: Now, you have just earned 200 reputation points sir! :-) Thank you a lot! Now it works like a charm!

Comment: Ooops, I am allowed to give it to you in 16 hours ;)

Answer (score 3):

Old answer: RewriteRule does not accept leading slash. Try to change to

```
RewriteRule ^new-site/(.*)$ /$1  [R=301,L]
```

**Edit**:
Version that is provided by you will forward to the cyclic redirection. To avoid it, I think, you can use such .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^new-site/ - [R=404,L]

# 2. Make sure that example.com is internally handled by files in '/new-site'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new-site/$1 [L]
```

Direct asking /new-site/* wil receive 404 error, while url exaple.com/* wil be redirected to /new-site
And notice that if there are files with the same name, for example, /r.jpg and /new-site/r.jpg, the last never be achieve

Comment: Hmmm it still doesn't work. I'm getting HTTP 200 status.

Comment: status 200 means "OK"

Comment: I know, but we are expecting `301`, aren't we? :)

Comment: Yes.:) To be honest, I do not completely understand your logic with recursive redirection. But I am sure that the first RewriteRule should work if the input www.examle.com/new-site ...

Comment: This is not really recursive redirection - I just want to avoid duplicated content for the subfolder.

Comment: I have read several times and  understand. Remove 1st rule from htaccess and read about robot.txt.

Comment: Did you try adding `Options -Multiviews` to your .htaccess file?

Comment: i still thinking  that it is better to use robot.txt to close /new-site/ from indexing. But i've written update to my answer yet